# Running Ruby methods via cron having issues

Tags: apache-2.2, cron, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phusion-passenger

So I have a method that is run every 10 minutes (Background.cron) to be exact.

Background.cron loops through a set of database rows and if certain criteria are met, an ActionMailer method is run to send out an email.

But what seems to be happening is (according to my logs) when the ActionMailer method is run, the Background.cron method stops until the next cron job is ready to start.

What could the explanation for this be?

Server setup is Apache 2 with Passenger and Ruby Enterprise Edition.

PassengerMaxPoolSize is set to 10 and PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp is 5.

I have a 512MB slice on Slicehost.

Comment: This sounds like a job for... stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Ruby script is bombing at that point.  Wrap your mail methods and catch any exceptions raised, and log? Also, check your user's local mail spool. Cron may have already emailed you a Ruby BT.

Comment: Checking the mail methods ended up exposing the issue.